# How to align your radiobutton side by side in bootstrap?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have radioButton, but they somehow not align side by side to each other, they not in-line to each other and its not good for user experience. I need some help here below to align them side by side(form-line) be closely seperated with enough space.

```
 <div class="modal-body">
                        <form class="dl-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="Text" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Add users()by</label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                    <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">EmailAddress</label>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "EmailAddress")
                                </div>
                                <label for="LoginID" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">LoginID</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LoginID, "LoginID")
                                </div>
                                <label for="SIS_ID" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">SIS_ID</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SIS_ID, "SIS_ID")
                                </div>
                            </div>



                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange your code slightly and assign proper column widths so that you take advantage of the 12-column system:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "EmailAddress")
        <label for="EmailAddress" class="col-form-label">EmailAddress</label>
    </div>            
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.LoginID, "LoginID")
        <label for="LoginID" class="col-form-label">LoginID</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SIS_ID, "SIS_ID")
        <label for="SIS_ID" class="col-form-label">SIS_ID</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the column containers are each set to 4 (`4 x 3 = 12`). I have rearranged the labels so that they appear after the radio buttons and taken away their bootstrap column css classes as they are not necessary. I also moved them into their appropriate column containers.

If this doesn't work, then you you have other styles in your CSS interfering with your layout.

Comment: thanks so much mate, see the difference now on the div size